# Implementing IComparable<T> in Generics: how can I access the Generic's Value?

Tags: .net, generics, icomparable

I have a generic class as follows (`Value` is `Public` only for the sake of simplicity, in reality, it's all encapsulated in properties):

```
Public MustInherit Class GenericInterval(Of T As {Structure, IComparable})
    Public Value As T                     
End Class
```

I want to implement `IComparable(Of T)`:

```
Public MustInherit Class GenericInterval(Of T As {Structure, IComparable})
    Implements IComparable(Of T)

    Public Value As T                     

    Public Function CompareTo(Other As T) As Int32 Implements IComparable(Of T).CompareTo
        Return Value.CompareTo(Other)
    End Function
End Class
```

But is this really correct? It feels somewhat "unmatching", as if I'd compare a value with a generic type.

In a test module I instantiate 2 variables and assign them values.

```
Dim lTest1 As New GenericInterval()
Dim lTest2 As New GenericInterval()

lTest1.Value = 4
lTest2.Value = 5
```

Now I'd expect to compare `lTest1` with `lTest2`. However, I need to perform the test on the extracted `Value`:

```
If lTest1.CompareTo(lTest2.Value) >= 0 Then
End If
```

But by doing so, I could as well just use

```
If lTest1.Value >= lTest2.Value Then ...
```

omiting the interface altogether.

Wouldn't it be advantageous to allow me to access `Value` already in the generic `CompareTo`, such:

```
Return Value.CompareTo(Other.Value)
```

However, `Value` is not an accessible member in the generic.

Do I miss something here, or is this unaccessibility by design? If so, what is the purpose?

Comment: Do you not want to be `IComparable(Of GenericInterval(Of T))` instead?

Comment: Take Magnus's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `IComparable(Of GenericInterval(Of T))`

```
Public Class GenericInterval(Of T As {Structure, IComparable})
    Implements IComparable(Of GenericInterval(Of T))

    Public Sub New(value As T)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Readonly Value As T

    Public Function CompareTo(other As GenericInterval(Of T)) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of GenericInterval(Of T)).CompareTo
        Return Value.CompareTo(other.Value)
    End Function
End Class
```

Test:

```
Sub Main
    Dim lTest1 As New GenericInterval(Of Integer)(4)
    Dim lTest2 As New GenericInterval(Of Integer)(5)

    Console.WriteLine(lTest2.CompareTo(lTest1))
End Sub
```

If `T` is `Structure` and `Value` only property you might want to turn `GenericInterval` into a structure also. (it would need to be immutable)

Comment: Not simply T, of course! Value is not the only property. I considered structures heavily already, but there are 6 constructors, 1 of them is a required empty New() constructor to initialize default values different from the standard. There were other quirks, ultimately turning the structure into a hack.